# Is It Reasonable to Get NaN Outputs With Identity Activation Functions

Tags: neural-networks, activation-functions

I made my own Neural Network from scratch in unity with C# and I am using it as DQN. ***I set up my network which has 4 layers: 9 input values, 20 nodes in the second layer, 15 nodes in the third layer, and 8 outputs***. I set all the layers' **activation functions as Identity** (which has no impact on the value), and the loss function as **MSE** I scaled my inputs and rewards, so my input values are between 0-1, and targets are between -1 and 1.

But after the first training, the weights become **NaN**. On another project I have a **much simpler network which is 5-4-3-2 nodes** in layers. And there it works perfectly. But when I increase the nodes for layers it immediately makes the weights NaN. If I add a **coefficient factor** to Identity something like **0.1** it doesn't give NaN but this time the 8 output values become very ***similar*** to each other.

I debugged the delta values and after 6 or 7 epochs later the weights go to very large numbers like 2345221. Than after that they become NaN, I think due to large values.

With other ***activation function(TanH, sigmoid)*** they don't give that NaN values but the outputs are become very **close to 1**(I understand that because the network has very nodes and the outputs are larger than 3 or 4 and this functions converge to 1 with larger values than 2). But this NaN thing happens with the ReLU functions too.

**My question is:** Is it normal to have this numbers or something is wrong with my code? If it is normal what can I do because the other functions also give bad results, I am trying to predict the cumulative reward here.

Answer (score 0):

Having **NaN** might be because of the ***exploding gradient*** problem. This happens when your model learns very slowly and perhaps the training stagnates at a very early stage just after a few iterations.

Comment: I don't think it is because of slow learning because when I made the learning rate 0.001, it stopped giving NaN values. I think it is the opposite.